# Unmarshalling SOAP: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"$URI", local:"getCardsResponse"). Expected elements are <{$URI}return>

Tags: java, xml, soap, unmarshalling

I'm having trouble trying to unmarshal a SOAP response from an XML file that I'd saved to use as a test sample. Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"{$URI}", local:"getCardsResponse"). Expected elements are <{{$URI}}return>

    at {$COMPANY}.MarketLoaderTests.unmarshalToGetCardsResponse(MarketLoaderTests.java:108)
    at {$COMPANY}.MarketLoaderTests.unmarshalFromTestSportechSoapFile(MarketLoaderTests.java:114)
    at {$COMPANY}.MarketLoaderTests.runSoapFileThroughMarketLoader(MarketLoaderTests.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:200)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.run(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:38)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:382)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$2.call(ThreadUtil.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"{$URI}", local:"getCardsResponse"). Expected elements are <{{$URI}}return>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:726)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:242)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:538)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:229)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:112)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:337)
    at {$COMPANY}.MarketLoaderTests.unmarshalToGetCardsResponse(MarketLoaderTests.java:103)
    ... 30 more
```

Here's my code:

```
  private static SlCardDetailsResp.Cards unmarshalToGetCardsResponse(final String soapResponse) {
    try {
      final SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,
          new ByteArrayInputStream(soapResponse.getBytes()));
      final SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
      final SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
      final Document soapBodyAsDoc = body.extractContentAsDocument();
      //final DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(soapBodyAsDoc);
      final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(GetCardsResponse.class);

      final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      final GetCardsResponse getCardsResponse = (GetCardsResponse) unmarshaller
          .unmarshal(soapBodyAsDoc);
      final SlCardDetailsResp.Cards responseCards = getCardsResponse.getReturn().getCards();
      return responseCards;
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }
```

I get the UnmarshalException when trying to instantiate *getCardsResponse*. The GetCardsResponse class was generated using a bindings script performed on a WSDL file.

Here's the first 10 lines of the XML I'm trying to parse:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns2:getCardsResponse xmlns:ns2="{$URI}">
      <return>
        <status>1</status>
        <cards...>
      </return>
    </ns2:getCardsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And here's my response class that I'm trying to convert my SOAP response to:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getCardsResponse", propOrder = {
    "_return"
})
public class GetCardsResponse
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "return")
    protected SlCardDetailsResp _return;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the return property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link SlCardDetailsResp }
     *     
     */
    public SlCardDetailsResp getReturn() {
        return _return;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the return property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link SlCardDetailsResp }
     *     
     */
    public void setReturn(SlCardDetailsResp value) {
        this._return = value;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed an XMLRootElement for **GetCardsResponse** because I messed up the bindings. Here's my updated code for that:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getCardsResponse", propOrder = {
    "_return"
})
/** Added this XmlRootElement annotation because the bindings were incorrect, 
 *  which caused an UnmarshallingException when trying to parse the SOAP response.
 */
@XmlRootElement(name= "getCardsResponse")
public class GetCardsResponse
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(name = "return")
    protected SlCardDetailsResp _return;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the return property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link SlCardDetailsResp }
     *     
     */
    public SlCardDetailsResp getReturn() {
        return _return;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the return property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link SlCardDetailsResp }
     *     
     */
    public void setReturn(SlCardDetailsResp value) {
        this._return = value;
    }

}
```

Also, I tweaked *unmarshalToGetCardsResponse()*.

```
private static SlCardDetailsResp.Cards unmarshalToGetCardsResponse(final String soapResponse) {
    try {
      final SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null,
          new ByteArrayInputStream(soapResponse.getBytes()));

      final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(GetCardsResponse.class);

      final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      final GetCardsResponse getCardsResponse = (GetCardsResponse) unmarshaller
          .unmarshal(message.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());

      final SlCardDetailsResp.Cards responseCards = getCardsResponse.getReturn().getCards();
      return responseCards;
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }
```

Comment: how you pom.xml looks like? I am actually can't marshall from soap to object like in you answer